# Is it normal way to use an iCloud container without publishing it to iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

Because I don't want to convert images to data type and save them, I am thinking to save them in icloud documents.
Apple's documentation says to publish an iCloud containers to iCloud Drive, but I don’t want to publish it because I don't want to show images to the user.

In this case, is it always necessary to set up info.plist as described in the Apple documentation?
（I believe the icloud container will be published to iCloud drive by setting Info.plist.）
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/synchronizing_documents_in_the_icloud_environment

Will icloud documents work without　info.plist's setting?

The settings in Info.plist are set to be hidden in iCloud drive by default,Is it normal way to hide it and use icloud documents?

I'd like to know if I'm thinking about it wrong in the first place.

Thank you.

Comment: "Because I don't want to convert images to data type and save them, I am thinking to save them in icloud documents" Saving an image in an iCloud document converts it to a data type, so it's hard to see what you think you're gaining here.

Comment: I’m still not good at programming so, sorry I cloud’t explain well,
I wanted to explain that “because I don’t want to save images as NSData in CloudKit, so I want to save images as png or something in iCloud documents.”

Comment: PNG is NSData. That is exactly what it is.

Comment: Do you have a solution to this issue now?